# Is there an example of an analytic function whose derivative is not analytic?

Tags: real-analysis

Can there be an analytic function whose derivative is not analytic?

Comment: I'm curious what definition of "analytic" you are using.  For most sensible definitions, this is question is essentially tautological.

Comment: Just note that, if a function is analytic, then it is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @Mhenni : but you have Real-valued functions that are infinitely-differentiable but not analytic.

Comment: @user99680 That is irrelevant.  We assume that the original function is analytic.

Comment: @user99680: my statement is clear.

Answer (score 3):

No. It is a consequence of the Cauchy theorem. If a function is analytic in any open set, it is the convergent limit of its Taylor series there.

Comment: So? Does having Taylor series prevent having unanalytic derivative?

Comment: Yes.  This works since the series in convergent in a neighborhood of each point.

Answer (score 1):

Definition: a function $f$ is *analytic* at a point $x$ if the Taylor series of $f$ converges on some neighborhood of $x$.

Lemma: If a power series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges to a function $f(x)$ on a neighborhood of some closed metric ball $B_r(x)$ then $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n a_n x^{n-1}$ converges to $f'(x)$ on $B_r(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you mean complex-analytic. By, e.g., Cauchy's theorem, if '$f$ is analytic, then so are $f', f'',....f^(n),...$ . And if $f$ is defined in a simply-connected region, then even $\int f$ is analytic.

Comment: What about real analysis?

Comment: Good question; let me think.